# Is there a better search engine than Google Book for book citations?

Tags: software, tools

Is there a better search engine than Google Book for book citations? When I try to search for a particular phrases, Google give me a lot of empty results, and not only that but they keep giving me fewer and fewer results. It's like they tried to cut down on cost so that a lot of results that should appear doesn't appear, so it's difficult to search for a particular phrase you've read in a book in the past, but you don't remember the full sentence. Is there a better search engine than Google Book for searching certain sets of phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no. I use Google generally, but I also use Bing when I can't find a satisfactory result. I have also used others such as WolframAlpha when I want statistics.

Try putting inverted commas around the phrase you are searching for (e.g. "economic impact of budgies") so you get the exact phrase. You can also use minus and plus signs before words to narrow your results.

Alternatively, type 'advanced search' into Google to get a greater number of options.